# Text + scalar features in one model

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I have a set of features including text field(3-10 sentences) and about 10 scalar fields. I need to predict another scalar field (between 0 and 1). I have this field in my training/validation data.

It's my first experience with a text feature. What is the correct way of creating a model?

Should I treat text field as embedding, flatten them to 1 dimension matrix of X size and combine with other features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fair enough. Create a low dimensional vector of text features or if your corpus of text is small (like in comments) then make a `bag of words` representation or `tf-idf` based word scoring (after cleaning) and use them as normal features by flattening them with other features.

The thing is if you go with word embeddings and when you want to un-blackbox the model you had created based on text, it can be hard as each individual dimension in `word2vec` does not hold any meaning. So start with bad of words and move to embeddings and see the metrics.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to use TF-IDF or Bag of Words. Should I use all vocabulary as features or better to reduce the number of features somehow?

Comment: That makes word vectors very sparse and if you had observed only certain number of tokens are presumably important from your data, then there is no point in using the whole vocabulary.